# Fixing the defect directly in Integration stream. Is it adviceable?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We are having many child streams for our development.

Few times we faced a scenario where people wants to do minor fixes. At that time, they will request us to use integration stream directly.

Is it acceptable to use integration stream for minor fixes? What will be the side effect if we allow to check-in at integration stream ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if those minor fixes are rebased in the sub-streams or not, after being done in the Integration Stream.

The best practice is usually, when fixes are done in Integration, to make and recommend a baseline.

That will mean sub-streams won't be able to deliver unless they rebase first that recommended baseline (if you are using the [deliver policy "`POLICY_DELIVER_REQUIRE_REBASE`"](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkproject.htm)).